# How to check passwords correctly containing "/+=@#^" using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a php functionality for password checking that works flawlessly on php. However, When I try to return the result from AJAX, the "+" symbol is somehow not being detected.

This is the php functionality:

```
function pwd_contents($pwd, $notAllowedChar)
    {
        $pass_array = str_split($pwd);
        $notAllowedChar_array = str_split($notAllowedChar);

        foreach($notAllowedChar_array as $nChar)
        {
            if(in_array($nChar, $pass_array))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['password']))//If a username has been submitted 
    {
        $pattern = '/\/\@\+\=\#\*/';
        $password = $_POST['password'];//Some clean up :)

        if(pwd_contents($password, $pattern))
            echo '1';
        else
            echo '0';
    }
```

And this is the ajax call that calls it:

```
$.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_check_password.php", //file name
    data: 'password=' + password, //data
    success: function(server_response) {

        $("#password_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {

            if (server_response.trim() == '0') //if ajax_check_password.php return value "0"
            {
                $("#password_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-success.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#c9dc54" style="padding-top: 5px;"> Password is valid. </font>  ');
                $("#btn-submit-2").html('<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"   id="b"  style="font-family: "klavikaRegular"; letter-spacing: 1px;" name="skip" value="0">CONTINUE</button>');
                //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
            } else if (server_response.trim() == '1') //if it returns "1"
            {
                $("#password_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-error.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#b11116" style="padding-top: 5px;"> Password is not valid. </font>');
                $("#btn-submit-2").html('<a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" style="font-family: "klavikaRegular"; letter-spacing: 1px;">CONTINUE</a>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How would I actually get the response to be return me the result that I want if the password contains "+" on it?

An example would be "Megason+2983". The result from the ajax call would give me "Password is not valid."

Comment: If you want to check if it contains those characters anywhere.  You could use the Regex pattern `/[/\+=@#^]/`

Comment: (I know this is off-topic, but) wow! `<font>` elements with inline styles. Really?

Comment: If you are convinced that the server side piece is bulletproof, what is the server returning to the AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the "URL encoded" method of providing your data to the AJAX POST:

```
data: 'password=' + password, //data
```

jQuery is treating the "+" in your password as a URL encoded character (it is a reserved character in URLs), and therefore it gets converted to its plaintext equivalent (a space character) before PHP gets a chance to process the POST.

To fix it, change it to:

```
data: {password: password}, //data
```

For future troubleshooting of AJAX requests: inspecting the request via developer tools in the browser would have probably pointed you to the solution pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a shorter solution. I managed to also get the proper behavior using:  <code> `data: "password="+encodeURIComponent(password),` </code>

Comment: That would work too, but I would say that the object literal approach seems more idiomatic. Also keep in mind that if you ever need to pass additional parameters, your code will probably get ugly pretty fast.